# Extend a class + new parameter

Tags: java, oop, extends

Ok, here's the issue!

I have a class GetStuff

```
public class GetStuff {

   public GetStuff(String data) {
       // stuff
   }

}
```

In this class I have a method getMyStuff() which calls a second method:

```
getAllMyStuff();
```

Now, I want to extend my class so I'll make a:

```
public class GetSecondStuff extends GetStuff {

      public GetSecondStuff(String data, int newData) {
           super(data);
      }

}
```

in this 2nd class I will override my getAllMyStuffMethod, but inside this method I'll need to use the newData parameter from the constructor:

```
private String getAllMyStuffMethod() {
   if (newData==0) // do something
}
```

How can I use here **newData** ? :(

Comment: Your class names should be nouns.

Comment: @AdamArold I used this quick names in order to quickly expose here the problem, but thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class GetStuff {
    public GetStuff(String data) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}

public class GetSecondStuff extends GetStuff {
    private int newData;

    public GetSecondStuff(String data, int newData) {
        super(data);
        this.newData = newData;


        data = "GetSecondStuff";        
        System.out.println(data);

        System.out.println(getAllMyStuffMethod());

    }

    private String getAllMyStuffMethod() {
        String ret=null;
          if (this.newData==0)
              ret="0";
          else
              ret="1";

        return "new data : "+ret;
    }
}

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        GetSecondStuff gf2 = new GetSecondStuff("GetStuff",1);      
    }

}
```

OUTPUT :

GetStuff

GetSecondStuff

new data : 1

Comment: the thing is that line "newData = _newData;" is executed after super()... and the method which I'm trying to override it is executed when calling super(). So using newData there will produce a NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new field in the **GetSecondStuff** class and assign it in the constructor. Then you can use newData in the overriden method.

Comment: if I add private String newData;
I can use it in the constructor only after the super()... And the function getAllMyStuff() is called from super() so, it doesn't help :e :(

or i missunderstood?

Comment: basically, but your constructor takes an `int`

Comment: Well, you're right - But if something like this happens, you should think about your design. Otherwise, you could do the stuff of super() in your constructor yourself, but that's bad design, too.

Answer (score 1):

save the variable newData in an instance-variable. with this u have access to it in the class GetSecondStuff.

something like:

```
public class GetSecondStuff extends GetStuff {
    private int newData;

    public GetSecondStuff(String data, int newData) {
      super(data);
      this.newData = newData;
    }

    private String getAllMyStuffMethod() {
      if (this.newData==0) // do something
    }
  }
```

**Edit**:

In one of the comments i read that u want to use a subclass-parameter in the super-class. so can u tell me why the new parameter is not in the super-class?

Comment: it comes from a different class

Comment: what do u mean? perhaps it would help, if u can give us a more concrete example of what u want to achieve. so we can give u more detailed tips?

Answer (score 1):

the class extending the first one may have its own properties, use them.

```
public class GetSecondStuff extends GetStuff {
  int _newData
  public GetSecondStuff(String data, int newData) {
       super(data);
       _newData = newData;
  }


   private String getAllMyStuffMethod() {
     if (_newData==0) // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: the thing is that line _newData = newData; is executed after super()... and the method which I'm trying to override it is executed when calling super().

Comment: I can't get your problem. It seems you need to modify the base class, not its extension.